# how to get the "role assignments" details each azure resources wise?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am looking some Power shell script , Where I can fetch all "role assignments" details including.

```
  Name ,       Type ,    Role , Scope , Condition
----------------------------------------------------
  <App>     <app>       Owner/Contributor      Subscription
  <userid>  <User>      Guest                  Management Group
  <GroupID> <Group>     Reader
```

So lets I have more than 50 subscriptions and under each subscription having 100 resources,
I want some cumulative report where I need to know resources wise user and role assignment details.

Script

```
   $resource = (Get-AzureRmResource | Select-Object ResourceId).ResourceId 

    foreach ($item in $resource)
    {
        $role += Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -Scope $item 
    }

    $role | Export-CSV C:\test.csv
```

Comment: What have you tried on your own? Stack Overflow is here to provide you with help with your implementation, not to provide the implementation for you.

Comment: @Daniel : What I have tried is this script  $resource = (Get-AzureRmResource | Select-Object ResourceId ).ResourceId 
foreach($item in $resource){
 $role += Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -Scope $item 
}
$role | Export-CSV C:\test.csv

Comment: Its giving me all the role assignments excluding the resource wise, I need to add the one more column resource name, Can you tell me how to do that?